# Looking for Top Line User Cumulitive report for Downline Users in PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

```
User Table
------------------------------------------
|userid |type   |reseller   |username   |
------------------------------------------
|1      |A      |1          |admin      |
|2      |R      |1          |user2      |
|3      |R      |1          |user3      |
|4      |C      |2          |user4      |
|5      |C      |2          |user5      |
|6      |C      |3          |user6      |
|7      |C      |3          |user7      |
------------------------------------------
```

A for admin, R for reseller  and C for client

```
SMS Summary table
----------------------------------
|userid |totalsms   |date       |
----------------------------------
|2      |10         |13-01-2015 |
|3      |20         |13-01-2015 |
|4      |30         |13-01-2015 |
|5      |30         |13-01-2015 |
|6      |40         |13-01-2015 |
|7      |50         |13-01-2015 |
|2      |20         |13-01-2015 |
----------------------------------
```

Result required

```
----------------------------------
|resellername   |totalsms       |
----------------------------------
|user2          |90             |
|user3          |110            |
----------------------------------
```

result is calculated as

```
 userid2 = `10+20` + downline userid4 and userid5 = `30+30`
 userid3 = `20` + downline userid6 and userid7 = `40+50`
```

Currently to achieve this, am running multiple queries like, first am querying all the userid from sms summary table and getting the username of the specific reseller from user table and then summing all the userid of 2.

I want to run this query once not multiple times, I tried several logics, but failed to achieve as I require it.

Please help... Thanks in advance...

Edited:
I have tried till here, where I get individual report, but not for reseller report with `join`

```
SELECT SUM(s.totalsms) AS totalsms, ru.username as reseller FROM smssummary s 
    left join  users u on s.userid=u.userid
    left join  users ru on ru.userid = (SELECT `reseller` FROM `users` WHERE `userid` = u.userid)
```

Comment: Read up on `join` and `union`.

Comment: Hi, I have tried join too, but not getting result for reseller, am getting individual, have edited and posted the code...

Answer (score 1):

you can do aggregation for reseller and then aggregation for clients and then sum up the totals
using `left join` to handle the case where reseller doesn't have any clients

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/699487/18)**

```
select T.username as reseller, IFNULL(sum(S.totalsms)+smsCount,0) as TotalSMS
FROM
(
   SELECT U.userid, U.username, IFNULL(sum(SR.totalsms),0) as smsCount
   from Users U
   join SMSSummary SR
   on U.type ='R'
   and SR.userid = U.userid
   group by U.userid, U.username

) T
left join Users U
on U.type ='C' 
and U.reseller = T.userid
left join SMSSummary S
on S.userid = U.userid
group by T.username
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this is not giving the desired output. Its counting only 2 row against 15and also totalsms shows as `NULL`, seems somewhere logic is inappropriate... not sure.

Comment: @sammry, added IFNULL to consider the NULL case, also added sql fiddle , so you can see that values are coming correct.

Comment: it still shows 0 in totalsms column for me when working with my own databae, I dont know what am doing wrong and again, am getting only 2 users against 15

Comment: Does it also matter if multiple resellers created by resellers? because my database has that structure, a reseller can create reseller and his reseller can create reseller and clients, so on. @radar... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/35619/1 check the fiddle now, i changed user5 as reseller

Comment: @sammry, it would require recursive query, my sql doesn't support recursive CTE, so new to use temporary tables and write stored procedure, are there known number of levels that reslellers can have then we can write it using left join